# Declaration is incompatible with PieVectTable

Tags: c, struct

My project is running on ccs 10.3.1. At this moment at **project>C2000 compiler> Include** option ,I am using 2 path(include_path,-l) like

C:\F2806x_common\include

C:\F2806x_headers\include

Take a look ERROR  console,

#148 declaration is incompatible with "struct PIE_VECT_TABLE PieVectTable" (declared at line 194 of "C:/F2806x_headers/F2806x_headers/include/F2806x_PieVect.h") F2806x_GlobalVariableDefs.c

I have been copied F2806x_GlobalVariableDefs.c from C:\ti\c2000\C2000Ware_3_04_00_00\device_support\f2806x\headers\source
This file is same from C:\F2806x_headers\F2806x_headers\source

F2806x_GlobalVariableDefs.c

```
#pragma DATA_SECTION(PieVectTable,"PieVectTableFile");
#endif
volatile struct PIE_VECT_TABLE PieVectTable;
```

F2806x_PieVect.h

```
extern struct PIE_VECT_TABLE PieVectTable;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* extern "C" */
```

Comment: The external declaration does not specify `volatile`, while the definition does specify `volatile`.  Pick one, and declare it consistently in both places.  They have to match.

Comment: Do you mean in both places it should be  ''volatile struct' ?

Comment: Either both should specify `volatile` or neither should.  Otherwise you will continue to get the error.  So either make both of them volatile, as you said, or make neither of them volatile.  If you want it to be volatile, then add it to the header file.  If you don't want it to be volatile, then remove it from your C file.

Comment: If we add volatile struct PIE_VECT_TABLE PieVectTable; in both places of header and source then 103 errors occurs mostly #10234-D: unresolved symbols remain. This errors indicates SECTION error in GPIO, PWM, EPWM, ADCREGS.

Comment: The declarations are currently inconsistent.  That's causing errors.  If adding volatile is causing errors elsewhere, then there's a problem making the variable volatile.  You need to figure it out.  If you can't, then pick one such instance and post it as a new question.

Comment: Well said. Most of the time I resolved errors those are arising for choosing  wrong file path  in  project>C2000 compiler> Include. Sometimes those collapse for version issues.  This project was build successfully with 2013 version of  C:\F2806x_common\include or C:\F2806x_header\include. TI suggested to use C2000Ware but previous files are conflicting with same rate!